# Foolproof way to check for nonzero (error) return code in windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

## Intro

There's a lot of advice out there for dealing with return codes in batch files (using the ERROLEVEL mechanism), e.g.

- [Get error code from within a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452046/get-error-code-from-within-a-batch-file)
- [ERRORLEVEL inside IF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367930/errorlevel-inside-if)

Some of the advice is to do `if errorlevel 1 goto somethingbad`, while others recommend using the 
`%ERRORLEVEL%` variable and using `==`, `EQU`, `LSS`, etc. There seem to be issues within `IF` statements and such, so then delayedexpansion is encouraged, but it seems to come with quirks of its own.

## Question

What is a foolproof (i.e. robust, so it will work on nearly any system with nearly any return code) way to know if a bad (**nonzero**) code has been returned?

## My attempt

For basic usage, the following seems to work ok to catch any nonzero return code:

```
if not errorlevel 0 (
    echo error level was nonzero
)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Sorry, your attempt is not even close. `if not errorlevel 0` is only true if errorlevel is negative.

If you know that errorlevel will never be negative, then

```
if errorlevel 1 (echo error level is greater than 0)
```

If you must allow for negative errorlevel, and are not within a parenthesized block of code, then

```
set "errorlevel=1"
set "errorlevel="
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (echo error level is non-zero)
```

*Note - I edited my answer to explicitly clear any user defined errorlevel value after reading Joey's comment to the linked answer in the question. A user defined errorlevel can mask the dynamic value that we are trying to access. But this only works if your script has a `.bat` extension. Scripts with `.cmd` extension will set your ERRORLEVEL to 0 if you set or clear a variable! To make matters worse, XP will set ERRORLEVEL to 1 if you attempt to undefine a variable that does not exist. That is why I first explicitly define an ERRORLEVEL variable before I attempt to clear it!*

If you are within a parenthesized block of code then you must use delayed expansion to get the current value

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
(
  SomeCommandThatMightGenerateAnError
  set "errorlevel=1"
  set "errorlevel="
  if !errorlevel! neq 0 (echo error level is non-zero)
)
```

But sometimes you don't want delayed expansion enabled. All is not lost if you want to check the error level immediately after executing a command.

```
(
  SomeCommandThatMightGenerateAnError && (echo Success, no error) || (echo There was an error)
)
```

If you absolutely must check the dynamic ERRORLEVEL value without using delayed expansion within a parenthesized block, then the following works. But it has the error handling code in two places.

```
(
  SomeCommandThatMightGenerateAnError
  if errorlevel 1 (echo errorlevel is non-zero) else if not errorlevel 0 (echo errorlevel is non-zero)
)
```

**Here, at long last, is the "ultimate" test for non-zero errrolevel that should work under any circumstances :-)**

```
(
  SomeCommandThatMightGenerateAnError
  set foundErr=1
  if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 set "foundErr="
  if defined foundErr echo errorlevel is non-zero
)
```

It can even be converted into a macro for ease of use:

```
set "ifErr=set foundErr=1&(if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 set foundErr=)&if defined foundErr"
(
  SomeCommandThatMightGenerateAnError
  %ifErr% echo errorlevel is non-zero
)
```

The macro supports parentheses and ELSE just fine:

```
%ifErr% (
  echo errorlevel is non-zero
) else (
  echo errorlevel is zero
)
```

**One last issue:**

Redirection of input and/or output can fail for any number of reasons. But redirection errors do *not* set the errorlevel unless the `||` operator is used. See [File redirection in Windows and %errorlevel%](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10354016/1012053) for more information. So one can argue that there does not exist a fool-proof way to check for errors via errorlevel. The most reliable method (but still not infallible) is the `||` operator.

Comment: It's worth noting that errorlevel is [not an environment variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx).

Comment: @NickWestgate - Yep, ERRORLEVEL is one of many "pseudo" or "dynamic" variables. I have identified and documented three classes of "dynamic" variables at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20169219/1012053, and within that post I reference that same Raymond Chen blog.

Comment: EDIT 2016-06-03: I modified the code to clear any user defined ERRORLEVEL to account for XP behavior that sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 if you attempt to undefine a non existent variable.

Comment: Stumbled across your answer while searching for checking for non zero error code. (Am converting a short shell script to run something on windows) It is astonishing that something which can be done simply in a shell script with 
var=$?;
if [ $var -ne 0 ] then
#Do something 
is so complicated and unintuitive in batch files.