# How to know whether a command is executed successfully via a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

For example, in a batch file, I typed the command below:

xcopy C:\fileA.txt D:\Dir\ /y /d

It will fail absolutely if there was not a file called fileA.txt. But I want to know if it fails, then output some messages to user. How can I do this?

Any help will be grateful, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foolproof way to check for nonzero (error) return code in windows batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935693/foolproof-way-to-check-for-nonzero-error-return-code-in-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most commands/programs return a 0 on success and some other value, called *errorlevel*, to signal an error.

You can  check for this in you batch for example by

```
if not errorlevel 0 goto ERR
```

xcopy errorlevels:

0 - All files were copied without errors

1 - No files were found to copy (invalid source)

2 - XCOPY was terminated by Ctrl-C before copying was complete

4 - An initialization error occurred.

5 - A disk-write error occurred.

[1] http://m.computing.net/answers/dos/xcopy-errorlevels/7510.html

Comment: Thank you! I don't know there is a variable used to store return value before. By my further testing, I must test the value of errorlevel from big number to small number. Otherwise, it will work abnormally.

Comment: Right! As it's noted in the link in the other answer, `if errorlevel` has this weird property: *it returns TRUE if the return code was equal to or higher than the specified errorlevel*.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are interested in is "error levels".  See http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php.  Basically, in your batch file, you can check the status code of the command (similar to Unix or Linux) by saying

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 <do something>
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 <do something>
```

where 1 and 2 are possible values of the status code returned by the last program executed.  You can also do something like

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

to print out the status code, but note that it does not always behave like a "normal" environment variable.  One thing that makes it different is that it does not show up with the "set" command.

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps me too. But I'm afraid that I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found the accepted answer didn't work but this did:

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto ERR
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following structure:

```
command > nul 2> nul && (
    echo Success
    REM can be multi line
) || (
    echo Error
    REM can be multi line
)
```