# Why can't I access a variable named __CD__ on Windows 7?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, environment-variables

*Note - this question is based on behavior observed on Windows 7. I believe the behavior applies to all other versions from Vista onward. Based on MC ND's answer, and Foxidrive's comments, it does not apply to XP.*

I can use the pseudo dynamic variable `%CD%` to get the current directory, without a trailing `\`. If I define a true variable named CD using `set "CD=someValue"`, then `%CD%` returns the value I assigned, and not the current directory.

A lesser known dynamic variable is `%__CD__%`, which is the same as `%CD%`, except it includes the trailing `\`. But if I do `set "__CD__=someValue"`, I cannot access my assigned value! I can use `set __CD__` to see that my variable exists with my assigned value, but `%__CD__%` always returns the current directory!

Does anyone have any idea how this `%__CD__%` mechanism works (why it is different than any other dynamic variable)?

Can someone come up with a way to access my `__CD__` variable using nothing but standard batch commands (without parsing the output of `set __CD__`)?

This is more an academic question, not a practical one. No one should be defining variables with names that match dynamic variables.

---

The reason I do not want a routine that parses the results of `set __CD__` is because values can have line feeds in them. Someone could define two variables, `__CD__` and `__CD__2`, or they could define a single `__CD__` value with a value containing a line feed followed by `__CD__2=...`. It would be impossible to differentiate between those two scenarios. (As I said, this is an academic question, not a practical one!)

Comment: Probably because Microsoft.

Comment: Does it have to be in Bat script?  If you use VBS, KIX, or PowerShell, your options are much greater..

Comment: @Leptonator He isn't making anything specific, he just wonders why he cant overload this dynamic variable and how this could be done.

Comment: I would guess that there's some hard-coded logic to replace both `%CD%` and `%__CD__%` with the current directory, and neither is a variable.  The `CD=xx` command is synonymous with `CD xx`, and is totally different from `SET CD=xx.`

Comment: @Leptonator - Good one :-)  Yes, I'm looking for pure batch. I suspect it may not be possible.

Comment: You maybe already be aware of this - There is Script-o-Matic from Microsoft..  Understand, it may not be exactly what you are looking for - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12028 but a good starting point.

Answer (score 22):

I have a theory as to how and why `__CD__` behaves so differently than any of the other pseudo environment variable.

I wrote a simple ENV.JS script to probe the process environment.

```
var env=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
WScript.echo(env(WScript.Arguments.Item(0)));
```

ENV.JS expects an environment variable name as the one and only argument, and simply prints the value of the variable. I did my testing on a Windows 7 machine. The script can be run from within a CMD.EXE console, or it can be run directly via a shortcut that defines the argument.

I will classify the various dynamic variables, showing contrasting behaviors, along with a theory as to the mechanism by which they work.

There are a number of dynamic variables that can be divided into three classes:

**1) Normal looking "variables" without any prefix or suffix**

```
CD              current directory
DATE            current date
TIME            current time
ERRORLEVEL      current errorlevel
RANDOM          random integer between 0 and 32767
CMDEXTVERSION   current extension level (only available if extensions are enabled)
CMDCMDLINE      the command line that invoked the current CMD.EXE level
```

The dynamic values are only available via expansion within CMD.EXE, and only when command extensions are enabled. They are not available via SET, or by ENV.JS. The dynamic values can be overridden by explicitly defining a static value using SET. The override values are available via SET and ENV.JS.

```
C:\test>echo %cmdcmdline%
"C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"

C:\test>set cmdcmdline
Environment variable cmdcmdline not defined

C:\test>cscript //nologo env.js cmdcmdline
cmdcmdline=

C:\test>set cmdcmdline=override

C:\test>echo %cmdcmdline%
override

C:\test>set cmdcmdline
cmdcmdline=override

C:\test>cscript //nologo env.js cmdcmdline
cmdcmdline=override

C:\test>cmd /e:off
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\test>echo %cmdcmdline%
%cmdcmdline%
```

The dynamic values are not really environment variables at all, which is why they are not accessible to the SET command or to ENV.JS. The variable expansion code in CMD.EXE first checks the process environment variables for the variable, and only if not found does it compare the name against the list of special dynamic names. Special CMD.EXE code must exist for each dynamic "variable" to derive the value from the appropriate source.

The behavior of this class of dynamic variables is described by Microsoft's Raymond Chen within his blog - [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx)

**2) Dynamic variables prefixed with `=`**

```
=ExitCode
=ExitCodeAscii
=C:
=D:
...
=Z:
```

Each of these dynamic values is undefined until some command is executed that defines it. For example, a brand new CMD.EXE console session starts with =ExitCode undefined. It becomes defined once an external command is executed that set a return code.

There is one exception in that the `={driveLetter}:` variable corresponding to the current directory will always be defined, even when CMD.EXE first starts up.

It is impossible to use SET to define any of these variables because SET does not allow `=` in a variable name. But the underlying process environment variable space does allow `=` in variable names. It just must be done outside of the CMD.EXE context.

I've written an additional TEST.JS to help test these variables:

```
var shell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var env=shell.Environment("Process");
WScript.echo('Within JScript: ExitCode='+env("=ExitCode"));
env("=ExitCode") = "override";
WScript.echo('Within JScript after override: ExitCode='+env("=ExitCode"));
WScript.echo('Within JScript test.bat return code = '+shell.run("cmd /c test.bat",10,1));
WScript.echo('Within JScript after test.bat: ExitCode='+env("=ExitCode"));
```

In turn, TEST.JS calls TEST.BAT:

```
@echo off
echo Within test.bat: ExitCode=%=ExitCode%
cmd /c exit 10
echo =Within test.bat: ExitCode=%=ExitCode%
pause
exit %errorlevel%
```

Here are some test results using `=ExitCode`, starting with a brand new CMD.EXE session:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\test>echo %=ExitCode%
%=ExitCode%

C:\test>set "=ExitCode=override"
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\test>cscript //nologo env.js =ExitCode
=ExitCode=

C:\test>REM cscript is an external command that set the value!

C:\test>echo %=ExitCode%
00000000

C:\test>set =
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\test>set ""|findstr /b =ExitCode
=ExitCode=00000000

C:\test>cscript //nologo env.js =ExitCode
=ExitCode=00000000

C:\test>cscript //nologo test.js
Within JScript: ExitCode=00000000
Within JScript after override: ExitCode=override
Within JScript test.bat return code = 10
Within JScript after test.bat: ExitCode=override

C:\test>
```

Here are the results of TEST.BAT that TEST.JS launched in a new Window:

```
Within test.bat: ExitCode=override
Within test.bat: ExitCode=0000000A
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I believe that these dynamic variables are true environment variables, which is why both SET and JScript can access them. (SET can only access the value using the special `SET ""` syntax.) The variables are dynamically defined (or updated) by CMD.EXE each time a relavent command is executed. ENV.JS and TEST.JS can see the value that was set by the calling CMD.EXE session. The TEST.BAT cmd session could see the inherited override value that TEST.JS set.  But JScript continued to get the override value after TEST.BAT exited because CMD.EXE was not there to update the value with the return code.

This class of dynamic variables is available regardless whether command extensions are enabled or disabled. The dynamic values are maintained even when extensions are disabled, as evidenced below:

```
C:\test>cmd /e:off
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\test>echo %=c:%
C:\test

C:\test>cd test

C:\test\test>echo %=c:%
C:\test\test
```

**3) __CD__ - A special case all unto itself!**
*EDIT - Actually, __APPDIR__ works the same way*

This dynamic variable is always available to both CMD.EXE and JScript. An override value can be defined, but neither CMD.EXE nor JScript can see the override value, except the SET command can list the override value. (Also, not shown, but jeb discovered SET /A can read the override value if it is numeric).

I wrote yet another TEST2.JS to probe this variable.

```
var shell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var env=shell.Environment("Process");
WScript.echo('Within JScript: __CD__='+env("__CD__"));
env("__CD__") = "JS override";
WScript.echo('Within JScript after override: __CD__='+env("__CD__"));
shell.run('cmd /c "set __CD__&pause",1,0');
```

Here are the results of some tests:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\test>echo %__CD__%
C:\test\

C:\test>set __CD__
Environment variable __CD__ not defined

C:\test>set "__CD__=Batch override"

C:\test>echo %__CD__%
C:\test\

C:\test>set __CD__
__CD__=Batch override

C:\test>cscript //nologo test2.js
Within JScript: __CD__=C:\test\
Within JScript after override: __CD__=C:\test\

C:\test>
```

Here is the result of the CMD.EXE window that TEST2.JS opened up:

```
__CD__=JS override
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If I define a shortcut to ENV.JS as follows:

```
Target:   C:\test\env.js __CD__
Start in: C:\test\xyz
```

Then when I click on it, I get an alert box stating:

```
__CD__=C:\test\xyz\
```

I find these results fascinating. The dynamic value must not be a true environment variable. Presumably there is a low level OS environment variable access routine that automatically returns the process's current directory whenever it is asked to return the value of `__CD__`. It does so, even if a true static environment variable named `__CD__` is defined.

The CMD.EXE SET command must access the environment variable differently than most other contexts. I imagine a C program could be written to get a pointer to the process environment memory and parse any true user defined `__CD__` value, much as the SET command.

Given that it is a low operating system routine that provides this value, it is not surprising that `%__CD__%` is available even when command extensions are disabled.

```
C:\test>cmd /e:off
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\test>echo %__cd__%
C:\test\

C:\test>cd test

C:\test\test>echo %__cd__%
C:\test\test\
```

I suppose the concept of a current directory is critical for every process from an OS perspective, and MS decided to give a process access to the value via a dynamic virtual environment variable. The XP OS allows expansion of any user defined `__CD__` override value. Perhaps that caused problems for some applications, and MS decided to modify the environment access routines (starting with Vista perhaps?) to always return the true current directory, regardless of any user defined `__CD__` variable.

So, based on the theory that it is a low level routine that is returning the current directory, I now believe it is impossible to use native batch commands to reliably get any user defined value for `__CD__`.

Comment: (Pure speculation) I'd suggest that %__CD__% is used by `FOR..%%~fa` where CMD has a filename for `%%a` but no path information; just re-using the 'grab from the environment' mechanism which essentially works as get-case-3,2,1. `SET` however only uses case1. `SET/A` would only use case1 because, if nothing else, case2&case3 return non-decimal strings. Hence, `SET` may assign a value to any valid varname, will LIST ordinary vars from the environment (case1) will string-assign (old mechanism) using case3-2-1 (the 'normal' sequence CMD uses to access vars) but uses case1 only for arithmetic.

Comment: @Magoo - There cannot be any relation between `%%~fa` (path of running script) and `%__CD__%` (current directory). They are often totally different values.

Comment: Ahem - er, not so fast! Try `FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "m:\ttf\u*" ' ) DO ECHO %%~fa` (where `"m:\ttf\u*"` is merely a source of filenames that don't exist in the current directory.) You'll find that `%__CD__%filename` is echoed. SET `__CD__` to whatever you like, the current dirname will STILL be echoed. PUSHD someconvenientdir before that `FOR` and someconvenientdir will be echoed. SET CD=bogus and the current directory will be echoed that is, ~f will use %__CD__% NOT from the environment where the directoryname isn't explicit.

Comment: @Magoo - Sorry, my last comment is a result of a quick response after returning from 3 pints of beer. My impaired brain saw %%~fa and thought %~f0. I'm still impaired, and I can't follow your various case terminology. I think I better wait until tomorrow :)

Comment: @Magoo - I think we have disproven your theory regarding `for..%%~fa` using `__CD__` by looking at the behavior on XP. I proposed the test at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=37066#p37066, and foxidrive provides the evidence at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=37080#p37080.

Comment: EDIT - Described the impact of disabling command extensions for all 3 classes.

Comment: Interessting that there is now a difference when extensions are disabled for `echo %cmdcmdline% %cd% %__cd__%`

Comment: @dbenham,  I see from your other posts that you do a lot of batch. Are you a sysadmin or something? Also, why do you batch instead of powershell?

Comment: @Pacerier - No, I'm not a sysadmin. It is simply a hobby. If I were a sysadmin I probably would be using PowerShell. I enjoy the challenge of pushing the limits of a seemingly crippled language like batch. Plus there is an element of nostalgia for me, as I cut my teeth on PC-DOS back in the 80s.

Answer (score 6):

[*This should be a comment, but it would be a very large one!*]

I would like to add that %CD% variable is also a special case for the following reason: if a `setlocal` command is executed and then the current directory is changed, a posterior `endlocal` command change the current directory back to the one active when `setlocal` was executed:

```
@echo off

echo Original: %CD%
setlocal
md newdir
cd newdir
echo In newdir: %CD%
endlocal
echo After endlocal: %CD%
```

This behavior indicate that %CD% dynamic variable is saved with `setlocal`'s and restored with (explicit or implicit) `endlocal`'s, in the same way of normal variables. However, a weird point is that this mechanism works *even if a user CD variable is defined* before or after the `setlocal`! The conclusion is that `setlocal` command saves the current directory *in an area separated from the environment variables*, and that `endlocal` command restore the current directory from that area.

Comment: Wow, I never noticed that before. It is certainly interesting that the variable affects the current directory instead of the other way around. I guess Raymond was sort of wrong when [he said](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743) `But you can’t change directories by saying set CD=C:\Windows.`, implying that the variable has no influence on the current directory.

Comment: This is not related to the `%CD%` variable, because the current directory (per drive!) is also part of the environment that becomes localised by `setlocal`, hence `endlocal` restores the current directory (per drive!) present prior to `setlocal`…

Answer (score 4):

I can't see the cause why a userdefined `__cd__` is different to a user defined `cd` variable.
But I made some tests.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo #0 %__cd__%
if defined __cd__ echo #1 It's defined
set __cd__=1234
echo #2 %__cd__%
echo #3 !__cd__!
call echo #4 %%__cd__%%
echo #5 %__cd__:x=y%
echo #6 !__cd__:x=y!
if defined __cd__ echo #7 It's defined
set __cd__
set /a result=__cd__
echo #7 %result%
```

So there are three interesting points.

1. The test with `if defined` is always positive
2. `set` can echo the user defined variable
3. `set /a` can access the user defined variable

Comment: +1, SET /A is very interesting, and a partial answer as to how to access. It seems that IF DEFINED returns TRUE for all dynamic variables. But I believe the underlying mechanism of various dynamic variables varies significantly. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this command line reference](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) there are read-only environment variables, where __CD__ is included.

From that page:

> **Undocumented Dynamic variables (read only)**
>
> **%__CD__%**   The current directory, terminated with a trailing backslash.
>
> **%=C:%**   The current directory of the C: drive.
>
> **%=D:%**   The current directory of the D: drive if drive D: has been accessed in the current CMD session.
>
> **%=ExitCode%**   The hex value of the last return code set by EXIT /B
>
> **%=ExitCodeAscii%**   The ASCII value of the last return code set by EXIT /B if greater than 32.

Comment: While this is all true..  There is another..  Having a look at for /? we can leverage: %~p or go even further to %~dp

Comment: I was aware of the dynamic variables with names that begin with `=`. The big difference with those is that it is impossible to use SET to define a variable with an `=` in the name. So it makes sense that they are read only. But SET does allow definition of `__CD__`, I just can't access my value after it is defined, and I find it mildly shocking that `__CD__` is such a special case.

Comment: @Leptonator - I'm not seeing the relevance of %~p. FOR variables are an entirely different construct from environment variables.

Comment: You referenced ss64.com, it's a good site, but some explanations are still not exact. And some pages are inspired by dbenham itself.

Comment: SS64 is good..  Another good one is http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php and does explain about the - %__CD__%  expands to the current directory string, always terminated with a trailing backslash

Comment: What can I say, good luck finding official information on something thats *undocumented*. The fact it is being preprocessed before the normal environment variables is obvious by now, but aside that any information about it is pure conjecture.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completion - And a way to get the correct value of the variable: Use the /I parameter of the start command to generate a new cmd with the original environment of the current process, without the changed variable.

```
D:\Sandbox>ver

Microsoft Windows XP [Versión 5.1.2600]

D:\Sandbox>echo %__cd__%
D:\Sandbox\

D:\Sandbox>set __cd__=hello

D:\Sandbox>echo %__cd__%
hello

D:\Sandbox>start /b /wait /i cmd /q /v:on /c "echo !__cd__!"
D:\Sandbox\

D:\Sandbox>echo %__cd__%
hello

D:\Sandbox>set __cd__=

D:\Sandbox>echo %__cd__%
D:\Sandbox\

D:\Sandbox>
```

Comment: I confirm that an XP VM allows the `__CD__` variable to be changed and echoed.  Windows 8.1 doesn't allow the changed variable to be echoed.

Comment: @foxidrive, in this moment i only have available a windows xp, can you test it in other OS?

Comment: @dbenham See my comment re Windows 8.1 above.  You can change the variable, and see it in a `set __` command but if you echo it then all you see is the current working directory.  Windows XP allows you to echo the changed variable.

Comment: @foxidrive - Yes, my question stemmed from experiments on Win 7. I didn't think to test on XP.