# Check if the current folder is the root directory

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I'm currently writing a batch file which starts from a specific directory - let's say `C:\FirstFolder\SecondFolder\ThirdFolder\` - and should perform a task in each of this folders, then go up one folder until it has reached the root directory (`C:\`).

The problem here is that the drive we are working on doesn't have to be `C:\`, it could be any drive letter, so I cannot just check if `%cd%` equals `C:\` to tell the program to stop going through every directory.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What if you say something like "if(current.dir.has_parentdir) then "go up" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this :

```
if "%cd:~3,1%"=="" echo IS ROOT
```

Comment: I just thought about checking the length of `%cd%` a few seconds ago, too. There should be no case where this check will fail, so it's working fine!

Comment: @JoelP, there is a chance of failure if someone do `set "cd=c:\somewhere"`, invalidating the test.

Comment: And, independtly of the users setting the `cd` variable, maybe i'm wrong, but the right test is not `%cd:~3,1%`? You can have a `c:\x` folder.

Answer (score 3):

The `%cd:~3%` test can fail if there is a user defined CD variable that overrides the dynamic value.

It is safer to use `%__CD__:~3%` because it cannot be overridden on Win 7 or Win 8. Not sure about Vista, but it can be overridden on XP. So this solution is no better or worse than `%CD:~3%` if on XP.

```
if "%__cd__:~3%"=="" echo ROOT FOLDER
```

See [Why can't I access a variable named __CD__ on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20156490/1012053) for more info about the odd behavior of `%__CD__%`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%a in (.) do for %%b in (..) do if "%%~fa"=="%%~fb" echo ROOT FOLDER
```

If the full path to the current folder is the same as the full path to the parent folder, we are at the root

Comment: +1, This can be simplified do a single FOR /F `for /f "tokens=1,2" %%A in (". ..") do if "%%~fA"=="%%~fB" echo ROOT FOLDER`. This solution is the simplest sure fire way to test. The `%CD:~3%` test can fail if the user defines a CD variable. Even `%__CD__:~3` can fail on XP if user defines value for __CD__.