# batch-file variable %CD% adding a backslash when run from drive root

Tags: variables, batch-file, cd

I have a problem with the variable %CD% in a batch-file. It adds a backslash if the script is run from the root of a drive.

as an example: **updatedir=%CD%\Update** & **echo %updatedir%** will return something like

- From a folder **E:\New Folder\Update**
- From a drive root **E:\\Update**

Is there any way to get rid of the extra backslash if run from root?

Comment: Although cosmetically terrible, the extra backslash does not harm...

Comment: @aschipfl  I didn't know that, but I just confirmed it.  Good to know...

Answer (score 4):

Yes `%CD%` only has a trailing `\` if the current directory is the root. You could get rid of any trailing backslash that might be there. But there is a simpler solution.

Use the undocumented `%__CD__%` instead, which *always* appends the trailing backslash. This makes it easy to build a clean path, regardless of the current directory.

```
set "updatedir=%__CD__%Update
```

Comment: Holy cow! How do you even know that?!  If this isn't in the _official_ documentation, is it at least documented _somewhere_?  (I see that this works, but can you also point to a source?)

Comment: @WesLarson - I think I first saw `%__CD__%` on a DosTips post by jeb, but I don't remember what the topic was. There is some unofficial documentation at http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html. You may be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/q/20156490/1012053.

Comment: Looks like [WINE](https://winehq.org/) (`wineconsole`) doesn't support that undocumented variable.

Comment: @palswim - I think I would be surprised if it did.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
set "CurrentDir=%CD%"
if "%CD:~-1%"=="\" set "CurrentDir=%CD:~0,-1%"
```

Since you don't want to go changing the system variable `%CD%`, this sets a new variable `%CurrentDir%` to the current value of `%CD%`.  Then, it checks to see if the last character in `%CD%` is a `\`, and if it is, sets `%CurrentDir%` to the value of `%CD%`, minus the last character.

[This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636381/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-a-substring-in-a-batch-file) has more information on using substrings in batch files.

Answer (score 3):

replace every occurence of `\\` with `\`.

```
echo %updatedir:\\=\%
```