# How to find where windows is installed using batch file

Tags: windows, file, batch-file

Is there a way to create a simpel batchfile that finds the drive where windows is installed?

Comment: Why do you intend to know where is windows installed?

Comment: Its for a script to fix booting problems that should be possible to run whenever you get boot problem

Answer (score 2):

Use `%SystemDrive%` from the command prompt or in a batch file.

```
echo %SystemDrive%
```

or

```
d:>%SystemDrive%
c:>
```

Comment: +1, But why double the percents in a batch file? You only do that if you want `%SystemDrive%` as a string literal instead of the variable value.

Comment: @Squashman: Oops. Was thinking of `%%i` use - don't know why, and did it wrong anyway. Corrected.

Comment: @dbenham: Corrected. See my comment above to Squashman. Not enough coffee yet. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ken White has the "normal" way to get the system drive via `%SystemDrive%`. But that variable can easily be corrupted by setting your own value.

An alternative that should "always" work for any Win version later than XP is to use:

```
for %%A in ("%__APPDIR__%") do echo %%~dA
```

Of course you can set your own InstallDrive variable to the value of `%%~dA`.

The `%__APPDIR__%` variable is one of two special dynamic "variables" that always report the correct value, even if a user tries to override the value by explicitly defining their own variable of that name. However, the value can be overridden on XP. See [Why can't I access a variable named __CD__ on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20156490/1012053) for more info about dynamic variables `%__CD__%` and `%__APPDIR__%`.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case 'finds the drive' doesn't just mean the drive letter:

```
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=2,5,6 Delims=\|" %%I In ('WMIC OS Get Name') Do Echo=%%I %%J %%K
Timeout -1
```

…and for no real reason:

```
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=2,5,6 Delims=\|" %%I In ('WMIC OS Get Name') Do (
    Set _di=%%I  %%K %%J )
Set/A _dn=%_di:~-1%+1
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=2 Delims==" %%L In (`WMIC DiskDrive Where^
    "DeviceID Like '%%PHYSICALDRIVE%_dn%'" Get Model /Value`) Do Echo=%_di% %%L
Timeout -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Type `cd %windir%` in a dos command prompt, and then press ENTER.
Note the current folder. This is the folder in which Windows is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need a batch file for that. Just hold the windows key and press R to open up a small window in which you type `%windir%` and hit Enter.

A Windows Explorer window will pop up showing the directory of the Windows installation. You can the click onto the bar, where the directory is shown (like the URL-bar of the browser) to get the direct path including any parent folders and the drive letter.