# How to write the letter of a removable device in a variable using the CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writing a program in `.bat`. Suppose the command prompt is at `D:\>`. I need to write the letter `D` in a variable. It's possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To save the ***current path*** as a variable ([much easier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61004879/12861751): `%__CD__:~,1%`):

```dos
FOR %%A in ("%__CD__%") do set "disk=%%~dA"
set "disk=%disk:~0,1%"
```

**Edit**: Alternatively,

```dos
FOR /F %%D in ('"prompt $N&cmd/k<nul"') do set "disk=%%D"
```

> Sources:
>
> - [Why can't I access a variable named __CD__ on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156490/why-cant-i-access-a-variable-named-cd-on-windows-7)

Comment: you can use directly `%%~da` and can put %__cd__% in double quotes in case the path have space. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need an additional **`for`** loop to define the driver, because you have a system variable **`%cd%`** or **`%__CD__%`** for  this task, use it through the substring variable

```bat
%CD:~0,1%

rem :: or...
%__CD__:~0,1%

@echo/%CD:~0,1%

rem :: or...
@echo/%__CD__:~0,1%

@set "drive=%CD:~0,1%"

rem :: or...
@set "drive=%CD:~0,1%

@set "drive=%__CD__:~0,1%"
```

**Obs.:** Also works **`%CD:~,1%`**, **`%__CD__:~,1%`**

**[String Manipulation in bat/cmd file](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

Comment: oh, i overcomplicated it. i don't know why i did that

Comment: If you need use **`%driver%`**, use: **`%__CD__:~0,1%`**  or **`%CD:~0,1%`**  is the value position (character) start in index variable position 0 and taken (~)1 place/character, don't need for loop (only for this set driver)...but you did because you are the **"Hacking Addict 1337"**