# How can I detect errors in diskpart when using a pipe?

Tags: windows, cmd, pipe, disk-partitioning, errorlevel

I am trying to eliminate the temporary script file (i.e. diskpart /s scriptFile) used to automate diskpart by replacing it with commands issued via a pipe, however I can't seem to figure out how to detect when diskpart throws an error. If you have a drive N: change the select vol n with a non-existent drive so diskpart will generate an error:

```
(
 (
  echo select disk 0
  echo list partition
  echo select vol n
 ) | diskpart
 set foundErr=1
 if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 set "foundErr="
 if defined foundErr goto :errorMsg
 echo Success!
 goto :EOF
)

 :errorMsg
 echo diskpart failed!
 goto :EOF 

pause
```

I based the code above on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10935693/foolproof-way-to-check-for-nonzero-error-return-code-in-windows-batch-file), but it's not working.

Is this even possible, or does the use of a pipe block or interfere with diskpart error detection?

Comment: You do realise that `set` will also set `errorlevel`? "a CMD batch script is more consistent and will set ERRORLEVEL after every command that you run" source http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html

Comment: I am using the cmd extension. I've read elsewhere that if, set, goto and a few other commands do NOT set errorlevel. However, in general I find the Windows .bat / .cmd language to be terrible, one of the worst for productive programming. In my 30+ years of IT work and all of the scripting languages I used or read about, Windows batch has to rank as one of the worst I've seen. After this project I will not use it again for anything significant if I can avoid it.

Comment: Yes, that would be because it was never designed to be a programming language in the first place.  It's a batch interpreter, intended for very simple tasks, and almost certainly not an appropriate choice for what you're trying to do - plain old C would probably be my first choice, but if you *insist* on using a scripting language, try Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it yet. but this should work:

```
(
 (
  echo select disk 0
  echo list partition
  echo select vol n
 ) | diskpart 
 if "%errorlevel%"=="0" (
if not "%errorlevel%"=="1" 
(
set "foundErr="
)
) Else set foundErr=1
 if defined foundErr goto errorMsg
 echo Success!
 goto :EOF
)

 :errorMsg
 echo diskpart failed!
 goto :EOF 

pause
```